# Ubuntu-Java not working in chrome or firefox

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, ubuntu

I installed JDK-7 on to my Ubuntu 12.10 and JDK is not running in any of my browsers but I can right click a .jar file and it will give me the option to open with OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime. I can also type "java into my terminal and get this

---

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server   to select the "server" VM
    -zero     to select the "zero" VM
    -jamvm    to select the "jamvm" VM
    -avian    to select the "avian" VM
                  The default VM is server,
                  because you are running on a server-class machine.
```

`-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose:[class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image`

---

Any ideas?

Comment: If you see this then it's already working.

Comment: Not having installed a plugin in your browser really has nothing to do with java being installed on the machine.

Comment: Two things: 1. Do `.jar` files run? 2. Every browser has a plug-in that allows it to run java... better check your browser documentation on how to enable java

Comment: but the problem is everytime I click on "Install Plugin" it just takes me to java's website to download java again

Comment: which is already installed on to my machine at /usr/java/jre1.7.0_17

Comment: really guys? -6 votes? how come? please give a valid reason to negative vote my question. Or are you just being babies?

Answer (score 1):

You need the browser plugin.

```
System > Administration > Software Center
```

Search for IcedTea. Check if OpenJDK is already installed while you are on it.

Install `icedtea6-plugin`. Go to `about:plugins` on your browser and enable it if it's not automatically enabled. Once you're done the software center window should look somehting like this:

[image]

You can do it via terminal too, check the package names above.

Edit: If you have Sun's java installed, make sure you enable the correct plugin on your browser, that is IcedTea for OpenJDK. I don't recommend having both Sun's Java and OpenJDK installed since you might have conflicts between both.

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal

**Chrome**
    sudo -s
    mkdir -p /opt/google/chrome/plugins
    cd /opt/google/chrome/plugins
    ln -s /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so

/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0 should be replaced with your location of jre

**Firefox**
    sudo -s
    mkdir -p /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
    cd /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
    ln -s /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so